# how do i submit row by row data to controller in laravel 5.2 after clicking the submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have brought some data after joining two table with the help of ajax, Now I need to submit those data row by row after clicking the submit button.

```
Serial_no|member_id|member_name|account_no|General_saving|Dps|actions
 1       | 1111111 | zia       | 01010101 |100           |190|submit


 2       | 2222222 |shishir    | 02020202 |100           |200|submit


 3       | 3333333 | shohan    | 03030303 |100           |230|submit
```

I want to click on submit button send the row data to controller to database. My HTML code is below which is blade:

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #EAEAEA">
<div class="form-group col-md-12" id="form-MemberPresentAddress-error">
    <h3>Account Information</h3>               
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th width="50px" style="text-align: center">No</th>
    <th>
        <a href="javascript:ajaxLoad('posting/list?field=MemberId&sort=
{{Session::get("posting_sort")=="asc"?"desc":"asc"}}')">
            Member ID
        </a>
        <i style="font-size: 12px"
           class="glyphicon  {{ Session::get('posting_field')=='MemberId'?
(Session::get('posting_sort')=='asc'?'glyphicon-sort-by-
alphabet':'glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt'):'' }}">
        </i>
    </th>
    <th>
        <a href="javascript:ajaxLoad('posting/list?field=MemberName&sort=
{{Session::get("posting_sort")=="asc"?"desc":"asc"}}')">
            Member Name
        </a>
        <i style="font-size: 12px"
           class="glyphicon  {{ Session::get('posting_field')=='MemberName'?
(Session::get('posting_sort')=='asc'?'glyphicon-sort-by-
alphabet':'glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt'):'' }}">
        </i>
    </th>
     <th>
        <a href="javascript:ajaxLoad('posting/list?field=AccountNo&sort=
{{Session::get("posting_sort")=="asc"?"desc":"asc"}}')">
            Account No
        </a>
        <i style="font-size: 12px"
           class="glyphicon  {{ Session::get('posting_field')=='AccountNo'?
(Session::get('posting_sort')=='asc'?'glyphicon-sort-by-
alphabet':'glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt'):'' }}">
        </i>
    </th>
    <th>
        <a href="javascript:ajaxLoad('posting/list?field=app_form&sort=
{{Session::get("posting_sort")=="asc"?"desc":"asc"}}')">
            General Saving
        </a>
        <i style="font-size: 12px"
           class="glyphicon  {{ Session::get('posting_field')=='app_form'?
(Session::get('posting_sort')=='asc'?'glyphicon-sort-by-
alphabet':'glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt'):'' }}">
        </i>
    </th>
    <th>
        <a href="javascript:ajaxLoad('posting/list?field=passbook&sort=
{{Session::get("posting_sort")=="asc"?"desc":"asc"}}')">
            DPS 
        </a>
        <i style="font-size: 12px"
           class="glyphicon  {{ Session::get('posting_field')=='passbook'?
(Session::get('posting_sort')=='asc'?'glyphicon-sort-by-
alphabet':'glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt'):'' }}">
        </i>
    </th>

    <th width="140px">Actions</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="searchShow" class="searchShow">

</tbody>
</table>
<div class="pull-right"></div>
<div class="row" id="totalRecord">

    Total: records

</div>
</div>
```

My jquery code is as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '#searchInfo', function () {
            var DomainName = document.getElementById('DomainName').value;
            var DivisionOfficeId = 
                          document.getElementById('DivisionOfficeId').value;
            var ZoneId = document.getElementById('ZoneId').value;
            var AreaId = document.getElementById('AreaId').value;
            var MonthId = document.getElementById('MonthId').value;
            var YearId = document.getElementById('YearId').value;

            var i = 1;
            var j = 0;

            $('#searchShow').empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: 'getSearchinfo',
                data: {'DomainName': DomainName, 'DivisionOfficeId': 
 DivisionOfficeId, 'ZoneId': ZoneId, 'AreaId':AreaId, 'MonthId': MonthId, 
 'YearId': YearId},
                success: function (data) {

                    $.each(data, function (index, subcatObj3p) {
                        $('#searchShow').append('<tr><td style="text-align: 
center" id="'+i+'">' + i + '</td><td style="text-align: center">' + 
subcatObj3p.MemberId + '</td><td style="text-align: center">' + 
subcatObj3p.MemberName + '</td><td style="text-align: center">' + 
subcatObj3p.AccountNo + '</td><td><input style="width:30%" type="text" 
Name="Dps" value="100"></input></td><td><input style="width:30%" type="text" 
Name="Dps" value="'+subcatObj3p.MonthlyInstallment+'"></input></td><td>
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="goDB"></td></tr>');
                        i++;
                        j=i;


                    });
                    // document.getElementById('hidden').value = i - 1;
                    alert(j);
                    $('#totalRecord').val(j);
                },
                error: function () {
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

this is my controller function:

```
 public function getSearchinfo(Request $request){

    $DomainName = $request->DomainName;
    $DivisionOfficeId = $request->DivisionOfficeId;
    $ZoneId = $request->ZoneId;
    $AreaId = $request->AreaId;
    $MonthId = $request->MonthId;
    $YearId = $request->YearId;

    $searchInfo = Accountopen::select('*')
                        ->join('members', 'accountopens.MemberId' , '=', 
 'members.MemberId')
                        ->where('members.DomainName', $DomainName)
                        ->orWhere('accountopens.DivisionOfficeId','=', 
 $DivisionOfficeId)
                        ->orWhere('accountopens.ZoneId','=', $ZoneId)
                        ->orWhere('accountopens.AreaId','=', $AreaId)
                        // ->where('accountopens.MonthId', $MonthId)
                        // ->where('accountopens.YearId', $YearId)
                        ->get();

    return response()->json($searchInfo);
}
```

Now I want to click on submit button and send the row data one by one. Please response me. I am using laravel 5.2 versions.

Comment: What is the issue with the above code?

Comment: there is no problem with the above code, my problem is how can i send the row data one by one after clicking the submit button with the help of jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a common `class` to all the `Update / Edit button` or `anchor` and pass the `ID` value against which row is updated. And refer the below example:

```js
$('.edit').click(function(){
 alert( $(this).closest('td').attr('id') );
  // make ajax call here
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td id="1">One <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="edit">Edit</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="2">Two <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="edit">Edit</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td id="3">Three <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="edit">Edit</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Use the above given approach and make ajax call accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#searchShow').append('<tr id="row"'+i+'><td style="text-align: 
center" id="'+i+'">' + i + '</td><td style="text-align: center" class="memberId">' + 
subcatObj3p.MemberId + '</td><td style="text-align: center" class="membeName">' + 
subcatObj3p.MemberName + '</td><td style="text-align: center" class="memberAccNum">' + 
subcatObj3p.AccountNo + '</td><td><input style="width:30%" type="text" 
Name="Dps" value="100"></input></td><td><input style="width:30%" type="text" 
Name="Dps" value="'+subcatObj3p.MonthlyInstallment+'"></input></td><td>
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="goDB" attr"'+i+'"></td></tr>');

$(document).on('click', '#goDB', function () {
    var attr = $this.attr();
    var parentId = "#"+row+attr;
    var memberId = $(parentId).child("#memberId").val();
    var memberName = $(parentId).child("#membeName").val();
    var memberAccNum = $(parentId).child("#memberAccNum").val();

    Then here you send post request to save these values to DB
});
```

You have make every row with unique ID to get particular row data so just make dynamic rows with unique ID and get their child data and pass as post request.

Comment: Thank you brother.

Comment: a null value has occurred when clicked. why?